# Vitest mock is cached from test to test

Tags: reactjs, testing, vitest

I'm trying to mock the `reactfire` library with different results in each test:

```
function getMockedAuth(type: 'admin' | 'user') {
  return {
    useUser: () => ({
      data: {
        uid: type,
      },
    }),
    useFirebaseApp: () => ({
      auth: () => ({
        currentUser: {
          uid: type,
        },
      }),
    }),
  };
}

beforeEach(() => {
  vi.resetModules();
  vi.clearAllMocks();
  cleanup();
});

describe('DashboardPage', () => {
  test('should render Backlog if user is admin', () => {
    vi.mock('reactfire', () => getMockedAuth('admin'));

    render(<DashboardPage />);

    expect(screen.getByText('Backlog')).toBeTruthy();
  });

  test('should not render Backlog if user is not admin', async () => {
    vi.mock('reactfire', () => getMockedAuth('user'));

    render(<DashboardPage />);

    expect(screen.queryByText('Backlog')).toBeNull();
  });
});
```

The first test works but the sencond fails because the mock is not overwritten. I've tried both `resetModules` and `clearAllMocks` methods but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Mocks are hoisted so only one will always prevail. I ended up splitting the two cases into separate files to solve this since vitest doesn't provide a way to isolate tests in the same file (that I know of).

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure Vitest to clear mocks. In your vitest config file, set the prop: `{ test: { ..., mockReset: true }}`

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to mock
one of them:

```
import reactfire from 'path to your module';

vi.mock('path to your module');

beforeEach(() => {
  vi.resetAllMocks();
});
    
   test('should ...', () => {
    reactfire.mockReturnValue(getMockedAuth('user'))

    render(<DashboardPage />);
    expect();
  });
```

another with vi.hoisted:

```
const { mockedMethod } = vi.hoisted(() => {
  return { mockedMethod: vi.fn() }
})

vi.mock('./path/to/module.js', () => ({
  reactfire: mockedMethod
}))

test('should ...', () => {
    mockedMethod.mockReturnValue(getMockedAuth('user'))

    render(<DashboardPage />);
    expect();
})
```